# My induction blower never stops

Tags: hvac

My induction blower never stops. It was showing a code of pressure switch but if I turned off the main power and then back on it would reset and heat normally till it was up to temp then shut off and do it again. If I unhooked the vacuum hose while it was running the flame would go out and the furnace blower would stop (not the induction blower) then when I hooked it back up it would start normally so I know the switch is good there is no problem with that. Th induction blower was replaced 3 months ago and has worked normally till now. The control board is also new.

It's a Heil H8MPN100J20A1 furnace about 10 years old.

Comment: I wonder if it is a clogged pressure port: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_BGCsv76ac

Comment: The air handler stops if you break the safety chain? That sounds odd. What if the high temp limit tripped... it's supposed to keep running the handler... - Is there another pressure switch somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

If it's an old **York**, that *is* your error code. Verify all limit switches, or find the reason they're tripping.